# Change font and components size

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

Is there a way to reduce checkbox size and font ? With this code :

```
 .mud-typography-body1{
    font-size: 14px !important;
}
```

the font size change but not the checkbox size

Is there a way to do it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use Size property

```
<MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@Size_CheckBox1" Size="Size.Small" Color="Color.Primary"></MudCheckBox>
<MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@Size_CheckBox2" Size="Size.Medium" Color="Color.Secondary"></MudCheckBox>
<MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@Size_CheckBox3" Size="Size.Large" Color="Color.Tertiary"></MudCheckBox>
```

I copy-pasted from the docs: [here](https://mudblazor.com/components/checkbox#sizes)